# How SELECT control work fine without (change) in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I am using the following method to get first `select` control value and according to that showing values in second `select` control.

```
<clr-select-container>
          <select clrSelect #getList1>
            <option value="">Select </option>
            <option *ngFor="let list of dataList" value="{{list.listid}}">{{list.list_name}}</option>
          </select>
        </clr-select-container>
        <div class="clr-row">
          <div class="clr-col-5">
            <h5>Select Segment</h5>
            <select class="form-control " multiple="true" name="segment_list" id="segment_list"
              data-parsley-group="block-1">
              <option *ngFor="let segment of segments | conditionFilter:getList1.value" value="{{segment.segmentid}}">
                {{segment.segment_name}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
</div>
```

Everything is working fine but the problem is when I select a different value from the first select control system didn't get any change event and nothing happened then, but when I click on page body (On Blur) the values filled in the second select control.

How could I set its behavior so it will work fine?

When I add `(change)="someFunction()"` it works fine, but I don't want to perform any action in the function, so I think it is not good practice.

Comment: can you make this app in stackblitz?? soo that we will get your error easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two way binding on Angular which is ngModel. Up to documentation of [clrSelect](https://clarity.design/documentation/select#guidelines)  it is supporing ngModel notation. Also you can check verry basic example for this example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rv84kd), so it should work like that

```
<clr-select-container>
  <select [(ngModel)] = "select1Value" clrSelect #getList1>
    <option value="">Select </option>
    <option *ngFor="let list of dataList" value="{{list.listid}}">{{list.list_name}}</option>
  </select>
</clr-select-container>
<div class="clr-row">
  <div class="clr-col-5">
    <h5>Select Segment</h5>
    <select class="form-control " multiple="true" name="segment_list" id="segment_list"
      data-parsley-group="block-1">
      <option *ngFor="let segment of segments | conditionFilter:select1Value" value="{{segment.segmentid}}">
        {{segment.segment_name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do not forget to declare variable as select1Value from your *component.ts*

```
select1Value = null;
```

Also if you do not have, do not forget to include FormsModule from @angular/forms into your module.ts

Answer (score 1):

Here example.
Sorry,I don't know how to put nice url for stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbsvk6